# Google Maps Location and Area Fields for Django

Tags: django, google-maps, geodjango

I am looking for two Django model fields that are easy to use in admin and gives a Google maps interactive interface.

**LocationField**

Stores longitude and latitude, admin user clicks on a map to mark the location.

**AreaField**

Stores a comma separated string of locations, admin user creates a shape on a map to mark an area.

I found a number of them but which one would you recommend for the above requirements?

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-maps
- http://code.google.com/p/django-gmapi/
- http://code.google.com/p/django-coordinatesfield/

There is of course also geodjango but it seems a bit overkill for this project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have been using [django-easy-maps](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-maps) but with a custom (non-admin) interface.  If Google can't find the location from the street address, we present a navigable map and allow the user to select a position, then store the latitude and longitude.  Otherwise, there is likely to be too many street addresses that the Google maps can't parse.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, we won't be using the auto address feature as we are mainly coding for Kenya and the lack of street numbers makes it hard to get exact positions from Google. I think we will just create our own two Widgets.

Answer (score 8):

I know this post is old but in case anyone needs another tool, i've been using the [django-geoposition](http://django-geoposition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#settings) app that helps to create a model field that can hold a geoposition and a corresponding admin widget.